# Change video resolution ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I have videos with different resolution. I want that all of them will be in resolution of 480x320. I tried the command:

```
ffmpeg -i %s_ann.mp4 -vf scale=480x320,setsar=1:1 %s_annShrink.mp4' %(dstfile,dstfile)
```

but the output of the videos are files with the size of 0 kb.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Impossible to provide an answer without the complete console output from your command.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I guess that really there are two questions here...

1. How do I batch convert files?
2. How do I auto scale a video?

---

### How do I batch convert files?

These scripts ought to do the trick...

**Windows**

```
for %%i in (*.mp4) do (
    ffmpeg -y -i "%%i" << TODO >> "%%~ni_shrink.mp4"
)
```

**Linux** (UNTESTED!)

```
for i in *.mp4; 
do
    ffmpeg -y -i "$i" << TODO >> "${i%.mp4}_shrink.mp4";
done
```

(I'm not too sure about the output file expansion in the Linux script, worth validating that.)

---

### How do I auto scale a video?

This is a little trickier. As you have your command, the aspect ratio is potentially going to get messed up. Options here...

1. Scale the video, ignore aspect ratio. Result = distorted video
2. Scale the video, keep aspect ratio so that the scaled height (or width) is adjusted to fit. Result = optimal
3. Scale the video, keep aspect ratio and pad with black bars so that the video size is exactly 480x320. Result = wasted/increased file size
4. Crop the input before scaling so that it "fills" the 480x320 resolution. Result = incomplete video

Option 2 would be the preferred solution, otherwise you are (probably unnecessarily) increasing the output file size. Option 3, I'll give a partially tested solution. Option 4 I'm not even going to touch.

**Option 2: Scale the video, keep aspect ratio so that height is adjusted to fit**

```
ffmpeg -y -i "%%i" -vf scale=480:-2,setsar=1:1 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy "%%~ni_shrink.mp4"
```

**Option 3: Scale the video, keep aspect ratio and pad with black bars so that the video size is exactly 480x320**

```
ffmpeg -y -i "%%i" -vf "[in]scale=iw*min(480/iw\,320/ih):ih*min(480/iw\,320/ih)[scaled]; [scaled]pad=480:320:(480-iw*min(480/iw\,320/ih))/2:(320-ih*min(480/iw\,320/ih))/2[padded]; [padded]setsar=1:1[out]" -c:v libx264 -c:a copy "%%~ni_shrink.mp4"
```

Comment: what if i wanted a fixed height and the width to fit? do i put `-vf scale=-2:320,setsar=1:1` ?

Comment: If you could give us a link that lets us understand what each token in the command means, that would be even better

Comment: I'm interested in distorted video (option 1). Working with an input video that's too narrow -- it squeezes things, needs to be corrected.

Answer (score 42):

You can use ffmpeg tool for it and enter command

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=480:320 output_320.mp4
```

---

or if you want to changing the video aspect ratio please use setdar

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=480:320,setdar=4:3 output_320.mp4
```

---

Comment: That doesn't work. The correct command format is
    `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "scale=480:320" output_320.mp4`

Answer (score 5):

I didn't manage to make video scaling work correctly from previous answers, so having looked into this myself, I wanted to add a current and more detailed answer to these.

### Scaling:

Reference: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling - please review this for anything not covered here.  This covers the scaling command very clearly with examples.  The `scale` command works for images and videos.

The most basic scaling command below will simply resize the video to the required size in pixels.  This can result in a distorted video if input and output aspect ratios are different.

`ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf scale=320:240 output.mp4`

To maintain the aspect ration, you can specify just the width, followed by `-1` which will calculate the height to maintain the aspect ratio of the input:

`ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf scale=320:-1 output.mp4`

### Compressing

If you also want to compress the video size, you'll find that the `libx265` codec is often recommended.  HOWEVER this does NOT work with the scaling command: in my tests I found that the color channels were positioned differently so there were visible ghosted overlays.

Instead use the libx264 codec [and add a -crf flag](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#Codec-Options:%7E:text=crf-,Set%20the%20quality%20for%20constant%20quality%20mode,-.).  [This should be the default for .mp4 outputs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17793150/6312186) but I recommend specifying it to future proof your scripts.

`ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf scale=1920:-2  -vcodec libx264 -crf 20 output.mp4`

Note: you'll also need to use `-2` in the scale not `-1`.  This ensures that the aspect ratio always conforms to the codec requirements.

### Testing

I ran some tests using a 4K RAW video shot on a Canon 5Div:

Original file is 2,128,665 KB

- Scaling to`1920:-2` at `-crf 0` results in a 847,266 KB file with slight quality loss due only to rescaling
- Scaling to`1920:-2` at `-crf 1` results in a 747,738 KB file with slight quality loss due only to rescaling
- Scaling to`1920:-2` at `-crf 10` results in a 191,491 KB file slight quality loss due only to rescaling
- Scaling to`1920:-2` at `-crf 20` results in a 19,735 KB file with further quality loss but still fairly good
- Scaling to`1920:-2` at `-crf 30` results in a 4,537 KB file with even further quality loss, use as preview quality only

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following command for upscaling and downscaling:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=640x480:flags=lanczos -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 21 output_compress_480p.mp4
```

Upscaling Video Using FFMPEG

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=1920x1080:flags=lanczos -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 21 output_compress_1080p.mp4
```