# What is the default FFMPEG codec for outputting images and what are alternatives?

Tags: ffmpeg, codec

I took a look at [Default ffmpeg codec when nothing is specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793150/default-ffmpeg-codec-when-nothing-is-specified). I see that the default codec is likely `libx264` for video. Is this the same answer for using an FFMPEG command to make a JPG?

If it's `libx264`, what would be a good alternative codec to generate an image? I took a look at https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/git-readme.txt, and I can't seem to find anything on what those codecs do. For example, searching `libzimg` just comes up with pages of people enabling it in a long list of options. https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html has no mention of `zimg`.

My current command is `ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -report -timelimit 9 -timeout 9 -i www.example.com/manifest -vframes 1 output.jpg -y`. I want to make sure I know what codec is being used when doing this.

I'm using https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/git-readme.txt, which has `mjpeg` listed. I just want to be sure that this would be the default, when nothing is specified. (I can specify things going forward, but want to know what would have been used before).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default JPG encoder is `mjpeg`. Default encoders are not really documented as it depends on your `ffmpeg` configuration, but you can refer to the log from your `ffmpeg` command.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -frames:v 1 output.jpg
```

Log excerpt:

```
Output #0, image2, to 'output.jpg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.42.102
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc), 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
```

So in this example the default muxer is `image2` and the default encoder is `mjpeg`.

Get more info on these with `ffmpeg -h muxer=image2` and `ffmpeg -h encoder=mjpeg` as shown in [What are all codecs and formats supported by FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20587693/)

Comment: Do you see the documented anywhere? I see it listed as a motion JPG encoder, but not that its default https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#mjpeg

Comment: Basically I need to be extra sure for licensing reasons :)

Comment: @DaveStein It's not documented. Looks like I misunderstood your question. Still not really sure what you're trying to figure out.

Comment: Updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: @DaveStein Updated the answer.